# I'm trying to expand the for loop in "ch = [ord(x) for x in cipheredText]". When I expand it I get an error message. (Python)

Tags: loops

I'm trying to expand the for loop in "**ch = [ord(x) for x in cipheredText]**". When I expand it I get an error message. This is to decrypt a vignere.

Here is the expanded form (not working):

```
for x in range(len(cipheredText)):
       ch = ord(x)
       x+=1
```

This is the error: **expected string of length 1, but int found**

Comment: why are you incrementing x? remove x+=1 and do `ch += ord(x)`

Answer (score 0):

You are using `range()`, which returns an iterable of numbers, while the list comprehension was directly iterating over the characters. The correct expanded form:

```
list_out = []
for x in cipheredText:
       list_out += ord(x)
```

This also writes the output into a list.

Comment: I appreciated the help, but the problem is that I'm still getting the error message: 'int' object is not iterable.

Comment: @CosmicLens in that case, you should give a minimal non-working program, as the problem may lie elsewhere